# How create iframe with XHTML content (So I can later access it)?

Tags: javascript, iframe, xhtml

I know two ways how fill iframe with content from JS.

1.

```
var pr_cont = '<h1>Hello world HTML</h1>';    
var iframe = document.getElementById('printframe');
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document
doc.open();
doc.write(pr_cont);
doc.close();
```

This way works, but by  default content created as HTML.

2.

```
var pr_cont = '<h1>Hello world XHTML</h1>';
var iframe = document.getElementById('printframe');
iframe.src = 'data:application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8,' + pr_cont;
```

Seems works too, but later I can't access to content.
Every time when I try access to content I have error "SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin"

Demonstration here: https://jsfiddle.net/8ytautre/

Comment: The full error is _"The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match."_ Haven't been able to make it work yet. Question: do you _need_ it to be an iframe? Anyway, the good news is that it does work in Mozilla.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Yes, iframe really needed for isolation.

Here I show differencies between XHTML and HTML parser and how works iframe isolation  http://pastebin.com/MGzZieqN

1. Print HTML demonstrate how work HTML parser.
2. Print XHTML demonstrate how work XHTML parser.
3. Print DIV demonstrate that occurs without iframe isolation.